# JavaFX and FXML - no data displayed in TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview, fxml, scenebuilder, display

I'm pretty new at JavaFX and i'm trying basic functionalities. I'm also using SceneBuilder (FXML) to create my views.

I created a `TableView` with SceneBuilder, with no columns (will be added in code) with id `tablePeople`. **The goal is to store people into this table, like many examples of basic use of `TableView`.**
Here is my `Person` class (I want to store every properties of this class in the table) :

```
public class Person {

private SimpleStringProperty name;
private SimpleStringProperty forename;
private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> date; 
private SimpleStringProperty message;

    public Person(String name, String forename, LocalDate date, String message) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.forename = new SimpleStringProperty(forename);
        this.date = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(date);
        this.message = new SimpleStringProperty(message);
    }

    // all getters/setters here
}
```

I correctly get my TableView from FXML:

```
@FXML
private TableView<Person> tablePeople;
```

At the start of the application (after loading FXML and before showing the stage), I fill my `TableView` with random datas by using this method I created in FXML controller:

```
public void initParametersView() {
    tablePeople.setEditable(true);
    tablePeople.setDisable(false);
    String dateStr = "01.01.2001";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
    LocalDate date = null;
    date = LocalDate.parse(dateStr,formatter);
    ObservableList<Person> people = FXCollections.observableArrayList(

                new Person("Name1", "Forename1", date, "a"),
                new Person("Name2", "Forename2", date, "b"),
                new Person("Name3", "Forename3", date, "c"),
                new Person("Name4", "Forename4", date, "d")

            );

    tablePeople.setItems(people);

    TableColumn<Person, String> tcName = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    tcName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("name"));
    tablePeople.getColumns().add(tcName);

    TableColumn<Person, String> tcForename = new TableColumn<>("Forename");
    tcForename.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("forename"));
    tablePeople.getColumns().add(tcForename);

    TableColumn<Person, LocalDate> tcDate = new TableColumn<>("Date");
    tcDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,LocalDate>("date"));
    tablePeople.getColumns().add(tcDate);

    TableColumn<Person, String> tcMessage = new TableColumn<>("Message");
    tcMessage.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("message"));
    tablePeople.getColumns().add(tcMessage);

}
```

As you can see, through this:

- I create an ObservableList of Person which is given to the table.
- I create each column which are (should...) using Person's properties values and add it to the `TableView`

**RESULT :**

**I get the TableView with the columns I created but datas are not displayed.** However, datas seems to have been put into the table, because I can select the first 4 lines of the table (4 instances of Person were created). You can see it here:
[image: Result]

**What I tried**

- I first tried to create my columns with SceneBuilder, get them in my controller and set cell values directly, but same result.
- I tried functions on table/columns like `setEditable`, `refresh`, but still no data displayed :-(

Where am I wrong?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Most probably the getters aren't named properly, or don't have the correct accessibility. Please post the value getters and/or property getters for `Person`.  

See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971109/javafx-tableview-not-showing-data-in-all-columns

Comment: @sillyfly you were right... I just generated getters and forgot to update it, how dumb haha. thanks!