# in TableView no columns appear javafx

Tags: java, mysql, database, javafx, tableview

I am trying populate data ito TableView but somehow it doesn't show anything

This the class where I create the arraylist using it as a type:

```
public class movieDetails {


private String movieName;
private String description;
private String movieLocation;
private String movieTime;
private int movieThreator;

public movieDetails(String movieName, String description, String movieLocation, String movieTime, int movieThreator) {
    this.movieName = movieName;
    this.description = description;
    this.movieLocation = movieLocation;
    this.movieTime = movieTime;
    this.movieThreator = movieThreator;
}

movieDetails(String string) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

public String getMovieName() {
    return movieName;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public String getMovieLocation() {
    return movieLocation;
}

public String getMovieTime() {
    return movieTime;
}

public int getMovieThreator() {
    return movieThreator;
}


 public void setMovieName(String movieName) {
    this.movieName=movieName;
}

public void setDescription(String description ) {
    this.description=description;
}

public void setMovieLocation(String movieLocation) {
    this.movieLocation=movieLocation;
}

public void setMovieTime(String movieTime) {
     this.movieTime=movieTime;
}

public void setMovieThreator(int movieThreator) {
    this.movieThreator=movieThreator;
}




}
```

Then in the database implementation class I return this ObservableList

```
public ObservableList movies_listView() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

    ObservableList<movieDetails>  movieDetails_Table = FXCollections.observableArrayList();   

    Class.forName(driver);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,dbuser,dbpassw);
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT movie_name,description,cinema_location,time,threator FROM movie");

        while(rs.next()){
        movieDetails_Table.add(new movieDetails(

                            rs.getString("movie_name"),
                            rs.getString("description"),
                            rs.getString("cinema_location"),
                            rs.getString("time"),
                            rs.getInt("threator")


                             ));                                   
    }
            conn.close();


      return movieDetails_Table;  
}
```

And in the main class

```
TableView<movieDetails> movieDetails_table = new TableView<>();

    TableColumn<movieDetails,String> movieNameCal=new TableColumn<>("Movie Name");
    TableColumn<movieDetails,String> movieDesCal=new TableColumn<>("Description");
    TableColumn<movieDetails,String> movieLocCal=new TableColumn<>("Movie Location");
    TableColumn<movieDetails,String> movieTimCal=new TableColumn<>("Movie Time");
    TableColumn<movieDetails,Integer> movieThreCal=new TableColumn<>("Movie Threator");


    movieNameCal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("movie Name"));
    movieDesCal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("description"));
    movieLocCal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("movie Location"));
    movieTimCal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("movie Time"));
    movieThreCal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("movie Threator"));


movieDetails_table.getColumns().add(movieNameCal);
    movieDetails_table.getColumns().add(movieDesCal);
    movieDetails_table.getColumns().add(movieLocCal);
    movieDetails_table.getColumns().add(movieTimCal);
    movieDetails_table.getColumns().add(movieThreCal);


    deleteMovie_pane.setCenter(movieDetails_table);


 // this button to navigate the scene where the table in
deleteMovie_button.setOnAction(e->{

        try {



            movieDetails_table.setItems(db.movies_listView());
            primaryStage.setTitle("Delete Movie Scene");
            primaryStage.setScene(deleteMovie_scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Java_CinemaTicket.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

   });
```

Once I run the IDE indicate no errors but it show only one column fill with information but the rest nothin

The output picture

[image]

and this the database picture:

[image]

Comment: Where are you adding the columns to the table?

Comment: not sure really how to add them

Comment: Is it really easier to post a question here than to read some [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE)? Even the [`TableView` Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) include how to do this.

Comment: sometime it's just better to get the experience from the experts

Comment: @James_D I got issue not all the information in the database being populate to the tableview do you know why. I uploaded the question may you see it

Comment: Did you try searching for a solution to that?

Comment: @James_D I did but haven't found anything

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+tableview+not+all+columns+showing+data The very first hit on that search is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971109/javafx-tableview-not-showing-data-in-all-columns

Comment: @James_D thanks man the link is really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't added the columns to the table. Use

```
movieDetails_table.getColumns().add(movieNameCal);
```

etc.