# Java FXML Tableview with ArrayList

Tags: java, javafx

Hey guys I am trying to do a scorelist for a Jump&Run game for a project in university I am saving the data of a `Player` class with the attributes `nickname` and `finalScore` in an `ArrayList`. I want to show the data in a FXML `TableView` but it won't work and only shows no content.

I have already tried to declare the attributes as `SimpleString`/`IntegerProperty`s but it did not change.

```
public class ScoreController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Player> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Player, String> Nickname;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Player, Integer> Score;

    // Creating Observable Array List
    private ObservableList<Player> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    // Set up the Scene
    private Parent scoreList;

    void setUp() throws Exception{
        scoreList = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Score.fxml"));
        App.scoreList = new Scene(scoreList,800,500);
    }


    // Adding data to the Observable List and setting Column Factories
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        data.add(new Player("Chris", 11));
        data.add(new Player("Agil", 12));
        Nickname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Player, String>("nickname"));
        Score.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Player, Integer>("finaleScore"));
        table.setItems(data);
    }
}
```

I expected the TableColumn to show the data of the `ArrayList` but the `TableView` only shows 'no content' in this table.

EDIT Player class

```
public Player(String nickname, int finalScore){
    setNickname(nickname);
    setFinalScore(finalScore);
}
public void setNickname(String nickname) {
    this.nickname = nickname;
}
void setFinalScore(int score){
    finalScore = score;
}
public String getNickname(){
    return nickname;
}
public int getFinalScore() {
    return finalScore;
}
```

Comment: Show us the Class `Player` i think you named the get/setter wrong

Comment: most probably a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971109/javafx-tableview-not-showing-data-in-all-columns) - improper useage of PropertyValueFactory (as @Raw already noted). Anyway, to get help with debugging, you must provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 0):

You could try some changes

```
 Nickname.setCellValueFactory(col ->new SimpleStringProperty(col.getValue().getNickName());
 Score.setCellValueFactory(col ->new SimpleIntegerProperty(col.getValue().getFinalScore());
```

If its working, you have to look at the name convention for `cellFactory`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried out your code and this is what I can presume to be the issue:

`Score.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Player, Integer>("finaleScore"));`

You have mistype `finalScore` as `finaleScore`, which returns no values since such a property does not exist. However, this does not affect population of the values for column Nickname. So my second guess is that you may not have set the controller for the fxml file. Please check that in your Score.fxml code you have the line:

```xml
fx:controller="<your package name here >.ScoreController"
```

e.g.

```xml
<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" fx:controller="com.example.ScoreController">

<!-- other children nodes here  -->

</AnchorPane>
```

**EDIT**

Try changing these lines to simply be:

```
    @FXML
    public TableView table;
    @FXML
    public TableColumn Nickname;
    @FXML
    public TableColumn Score;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately it still don't work I already got the controller set in my FXML.

Comment: I have edited the answer to try out something else.

Comment: still no difference but thanks you for your effort :)