# JavaFX - TableView - setItems : The method setItems(ObservableList) in the type TableView is not showing me anything

Tags: javafx, tableview

iam new here so i dont know exactly what to do but i have this problem my tableview.setitems(oblist);
when i start my program the table view doesnt show me anything just strange lines inside the area

```
public class FXMLTableController implements Initializable {
private  Connection con;

@FXML
private TableView<LOC> tableview;
@FXML
private TableColumn<LOC, Integer> ttidLoc;
@FXML
private TableColumn<LOC,Integer> ttidProd;
@FXML
private TableColumn<LOC, Float> ttPrixJour;
@FXML
private TableColumn<LOC,Integer> ttMaxJour;
@FXML
private TableColumn<LOC,Integer> ttidClient;

ObservableList<LOC> oblist=FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


    try {
         con = DataBase.getInstance().getConnection();
        ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from locations");

        while(rs.next()) {
            oblist.add(new LOC(rs.getInt("idLoc"),rs.getInt("idProd"),rs.getFloat("PrixJour"),rs.getInt("MaxJour"),rs.getInt("idClient")));
        } 

        ttidLoc.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("idLoc"));
        ttidProd.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("idProd"));
        ttPrixJour.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("PrixJour"));
        ttMaxJour.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("MaxJour"));
        ttidClient.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("idClient"));



       tableview.setItems(oblist);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FXMLTableController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

}

here is my entities code that i work with

```
public class LOC {
private int idLoc;
private int idProd;
private float PrixJour;
private int MaxJour;
private int idClient;

public LOC(int idLoc, int idProd, float PrixJour, int MaxJour, int idClient) {
    this.idLoc = idLoc;
    this.idProd = idProd;
    this.PrixJour = PrixJour;
    this.MaxJour = MaxJour;
    this.idClient=idClient;
}

public LOC( int idProd, float PrixJour, int MaxJour, int idClient) {

    this.idProd = idProd;
    this.PrixJour = PrixJour;
    this.MaxJour = MaxJour;
    this.idClient=idClient;
```

btw im using scenebuilder and i trying to open the tableview in another scene when clicking a button on the first one

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`PropertyValueFactory`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) and made sure your `LOC` class has the methods that the `PropertyValueFactory` expects? [Edit] your post to include the remainder of the `LOC` class (ideally create a [MCVE] which demonstrates the problem).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javafx tableview not showing data in all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971109/javafx-tableview-not-showing-data-in-all-columns)

Comment: .. and please stick to java naming conventions :)

Comment: Does not explicitly say so in the docs but it might be that the fields need to be public for it to work

Comment: @Alex Never make fields public.

Comment: sorry for the name conventions plus im sure my class loc  has the methodes of PropertyValueFactory

Comment: i mean i saw another topic their problem was the getter and setters and theones im using are fine same name everything so thats not the case

Answer (score 0):

U can also use your own implementation of a CellValueFactory this way u do not rely on the reflection logic of the PropertyValueFactory. As an example:

```
ttidLoc.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
    LOC value = param.getValue();
    return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(value.idLoc);
});
```

Comment: Wanted to make a comment but then I can not format code there :(

Comment: yeah, code in comments looks crappy because there are not line-breaks .. but you can format single line code as code by backticks.

Comment: i did that the same issue occures i have noticed if i take off allthe cellvalue and leave the setitems alone the same thing show up so its not filling my cells

Comment: Well maybe there is nothing ever added to the ObservableList. You should go and debug this then. Set a Breakpoint after the while loop check if there is any thing in the list at all, or just print out the list or the list size.

Comment: And if there is something in the list try to break it down to an Object with one field and one hard coded instance etc. And create a minimal not working example so somebody can run this example and debug it.