# JavaFX populate TableView from ObservableList

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, observablelist

I'm trying to populate a TableView with data from an ObservableList. I've done this before but for some reason I can't get it to work now. I don't get any exceptions or anything but it simply doesn't add anything to the table.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035478/javafx-propertyvaluefactory-not-populating-tableview) question is similar but I identified another issue caused by JPA which made it so the mentioned constructor for `Modification` is never executed. Instead JPA does its magic to assign the values.

Here's my code - I snipped code that was irrelevant to the question:

**FXML**

```
<TableView fx:id="tblModifications" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="545.0" prefWidth="512.0">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="%itemNumber" fx:id="colModArt"/>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="%name" fx:id="colModName"/>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="%amount" fx:id="colModAmount" />
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Application implements Initializable {
    private TableView<Modification> tblModifications;
    private TableColumn<ObservableList<Modification>, String> colModArt;
    private TableColumn<ObservableList<Modification>, String> colModName;
    private TableColumn<ObservableList<Modification>, Integer> colModAmount;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1){
        colModArt.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("barcodeProperty"));
        colModName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nameProperty"));
        colModAmount.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("amountProperty"));

        admin = Administration.getInstance();

        tblModifications.setItems(admin.observableModifications); // This list is populated with correct data, I tested.
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("strings", new Locale("NL"));
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("main.fxml"), resources);
        primaryStage.setTitle(resources.getString("title"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1280, 1024));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**Modification.java**

```
public class Modification {
    public SimpleStringProperty barcodeProperty;
    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty;
    public SimpleIntegerProperty amountProperty;
    private int id;
    private Seller seller;
    private Product product;
    private int amount;
    private Boolean accepted;

    public Modification(int id, Seller seller, Product product, int amount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.seller = seller;
        this.product = product;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.accepted = false;

        barcodeProperty.set(String.valueOf(product.getBarcode()));
        nameProperty.set(product.getName());
        amountProperty.set(amount);
    }
}
```

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javafx PropertyValueFactory not populating Tableview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035478/javafx-propertyvaluefactory-not-populating-tableview)

Comment: And as addition: `private TableColumn<ObservableList<Modification>, String> colModArt` shall be `private TableColumn<Modification, String> colModArt` - this is valid for each `TableColumn` definition.

Comment: @DVarga Thanks! I did indeed change the names in the `PropertyValueFactory`'s which made it get the correct info. I then realised that the constructor is never called since JPA creates the objects with another constructor. I simply created a get method for the values instead which fixed it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this issue was caused in part by JPA.

First, I used the incorrect field names in the `PropertyValueFactory`'s. I had to remove the `Property` part from them because apparently this is added automatically (reflection?)

Second, the JPA implementation never executed the `Modification` constructor so the `SimpleStringProperty` never got its value. I resolved this by writing my own getters for these values: `getProductName` and `getProductBarcode`

Comment: It's probably a good thing your constructor wasn't invoked, as it would throw a `NullPointerException` if it were... To understand how the `PropertyValueFactory` works, read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html)