# Java: setCellValuefactory; Lambda vs. PropertyValueFactory; advantages/disadvantages

Tags: java, javafx

today i encountered another thing i don't really understand while trying to learn more about JavaFX and Java in general.

Reference is the following tutorial (im trying to apply the principle to an organizer):

[JavaFX 8 Tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part3/)

I will give a short outline of the particular part on which i've got a question:

My main window contains a tableview which shows some appointment-data.
So i got some lines of this style(same as in the tutorial):

```
aColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData ->cellData.getValue().getAColumnsProperty());
```

The data can be manipulated via an additional EditDialog.
That works just fine. If i edit things the changes are displayed immediately but i did some additional research to better understand the Lambda (not too successful). Now...in the online java documentation [Java Doc PropertyValueFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) it says:
"A convenience implementation of the Callback-Interface,[...]"

So i refactored my code into this style:

```
aColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Appointment,LocalDate>("date"));
```

Which i find much more readable than the Lambda.
But i noticed that when i make changes i need to do some sorting on the TableView before the changes are displayed.

Is it possible to achieve an immediate display of change in the second approach?

If yes: are there major disavantages which would discourage such a modification? I.e. would the Lambda be the best practice in this situation?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`PropertyValueFactory` expects correctly named property getters. `getAColumnsProperty` is probably not one.

In case of `new PropertyValueFactory<Appointment, LocalDate>("date")` the `Appointment` class needs to contain a `dateProperty()` method; the returned values need to extend `ReadOnlyProperty` for this to work and any edits will only lead to an update in the model automatically, if the returned object also `WritableValue`.

Example `Appointment` class that should work with `PropertyValueFactory<>("date")`:

```
public class Appointment {
    private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> date = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public final LocalDate getDate() {
        return this.date.get();
    }

    public final void setDate(LocalDate value) {
        this.date.set(value);
    }

    public final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateProperty() {
        return this.date;
    }
}
```

If no such method exists, `PropertyValueFactory` will use a getter to retrieve the value, i.e. `getDate()`, but this case updates in the model will not be visible in the UI until it updates the `Cell`, since the `PropertyValueFactory` "does not know" where to add a listener.

#### Disadvantages of `PropertyValueFactory`

- Can only find `public` methods in a `public` class
- `PropertyValueFactory` uses reflection
- Not typesafe. In `new PropertyValueFactory<Appointment, LocalDate>("date")` the compiler does not check, if there is a appropriate method, if that method even returns a suitable class or if e.g. the property getter returns a `String` instead of a `ReadOnlyProperty<LocalDate>` which can lead to `ClassCastException`s.
- No compile time checking. In the lambda expression the compiler can do some checking if the method exists and returns a appropriate type; with `PropertyValueFactory` this is not done.
- Does not work with [records](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/records-come-to-java). [(*JEP 395: Records*)](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395)

If you are sure to implement the appropriate methods in the item class correctly, there is nothing wrong with using `PropertyValueFactory`, but as mentioned above it has it's disadvantages. Moreover implementing the `Callback` is much more flexible. You could e.g. do some additional modifications:

```
TableColumn<Appointment, String> column = ...

column.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Appointment, String>, ObservableValue<String>> {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Appointment, String> cd) {
        Appointment a  = cd.getValue();

        return Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> "the year: " + a.getDate().getYear(), a.dateProperty());
    }

});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the time you invested in this elaborate answer! Please excuse me for the late acceptance. I need to check on my getters/setters again to fully evaluate my mistake(s). Many thanks also for your input about the disatvantages!

Comment: Is there a huge performance hit using reflection in this case?  Where would it be seen the most?

Comment: The failure to work with records is an egregious problem.  I hope it's on the punch list to be fixed.