# How to set list of map into javafx table view

Tags: list, javafx, tableview, fxml

The following code snippets show the declarations of the fields and how I set up the table.

Please tell me what went wrong. The data is not getting displayed.

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Map<String, Object>, String> productNameCol ;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Map<String,Object>, String> requestedBarcodeCol;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Map<String,Object>, String> pickedBarcodeCol;
```

```
productNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Map<String,Object>,String>("ProductName"));
requestedBarcodeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Map<String,Object>,String>("ActualBarcode"));
pickedBarcodeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Map<String,Object>,String>("PickedBarcode"));
requestedQuantityCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Map<String,Object>,String>("ActualQuantity"));
actualQuantityCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Map<String,Object>,String>("PickedQuantity"));


unMatchDataTableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(unmatchedBarcodeMap));
```

Comment: Read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049734/java-setcellvaluefactory-lambda-vs-propertyvaluefactory-advantages-disadvant question and the @fabian's  answer carefully and check if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question does not contain a MCVE, I've got to make some assumptions; the solution I present may not work without modifications. Those are my assumptions:

- `unmatchedBarcodeMap` is non-empty
- The controller is properly used when loading the fxml
- The fields contain the instances used in the `TableView` that is displayed on screen

`PropertyValueFactory` uses getters or property getters to retrieve values. These are not available for `Map`:

Let `<property>` denote the string passed to the `PropertyValueFactory` and `<Property>` the same string but with the first char converted to upper case:

`PropertyValueFactory` looks for a method named `<property>Property` that returns a `ObservableValue` containing the value to be displayed in the column first. If such a method exists, the result of invoking the method on the row item is returned from the `call` method. If this method is not available, `PropertyValueFactory` looks for a method named `get<Property>`; If this method is available, the result of invoking the method for the row item is wrapped in a `ObservableValue` object and returned from the `call` method. Otherwise `null` is returned resulting in an empty cell.

You need to use [`MapValueFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/MapValueFactory.html) instead of `PropertyValueFactory` to retrieve values from the `Map`s:

```
productNameCol.setCellValueFactory((Callback) new MapValueFactory("ProductName"));
...
```

This displays the result of calling using `rowItem.get("ProductName")` in the `productNameCol` column.

Comment: Thank you @fabian