# How to correctly set images inside TableView

Tags: java, javafx

Im trying to populata a tableview with objects thats have ImageView as one of their values, but only the last item in the tableview is displaying the image, none of the rest do

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    public TableView<Apple> table;
    public TableColumn nameColumn;
    public TableColumn imageColumn;

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("download.jpg"));
    Apple apple = new Apple("Bob",imageView);
    Apple apple2 = new Apple("John",imageView);
    Apple[] apples = {apple2,apple};
    List<Apple> appleList = Arrays.asList(apples);
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        imageColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("image"));
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory((new PropertyValueFactory<>("name")));
        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(appleList));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Apple {

    private final int SIZE = 20;

    String name;
    ImageView image;

    public Apple(String name, ImageView image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        image.setFitHeight(SIZE);
        image.setFitWidth(SIZE);

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ImageView getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(ImageView image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Im not sure why this is happening, i've seen people online setting the images 1 by 1 using loops though.

Comment: Your code was formatted as html, I [removed the html formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70619912/revisions).

Comment: Don't use nodes like `ImageView` as cell values, instead, just return a property which is a path to the image as a string (or an Image if you want) as the cell value and provide a separate [cell factory](https://edencoding.com/tableview-customization-cellfactory/).

Comment: Also, a node can only appear once in a scene.  So, trying to use exactly the same ImageView for different rows will not work.

Comment: A [lambda is better than a PropertyValueFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049734/java-setcellvaluefactory-lambda-vs-propertyvaluefactory-advantages-disadvant#:~:text=In%20the%20lambda%20expression%20the%20compiler%20can%20do,is%20not%20done.%20Does%20not%20work%20with%20records.), though, in this case, there is no issue with your property value factories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments by @jewelsea, your model class (`Apple`) should contain only data; it should not contain UI fields such as `ImageView`. Any `Node` can only appear once in the scene graph, which is why you only see the `ImageView` in a single row in the table.

You should instead store either the path to the image, or the `Image` (which is only data) itself in the model class. The trade-off between these two choices is a compute-time versus memory consumption trade-off. If you store the path to the image, the image will need to be loaded each time a cell updates (e.g. during scrolling), which takes time. On the other hand, if you store the `Image`, then all images needed for the entire table will need to be stored in memory, whether or not they are displayed.

I would recommend storing the `Image` in the model class if your table only needs a small number of images. This may happen if the table only has a few rows, or if there are a small number of images and multiple rows show the same image. Note that `Image`s *can* be shared by multiple `ImageView`s, so there is no need to load any single `Image` more than once.

Using `Image` in the model class would look like this:

```
public class Apple {

    private String name;
    private Image image;

    public Apple(String name, Image image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

You will need a cell implementation to display the image:

```
public class ImageCell extends TableCell<Apple, Image> {

    private static final IMAGE_SIZE = 20 ;
    private final ImageView imageView ;

    public TableCell() {
        imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setFitWidth(IMAGE_SIZE);
        imageView.setFitHeight(IMAGE_SIZE);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    }

   @Override
   protected void updateItem(Image image, boolean empty) {
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            imageView.setImage(image);
            setGraphic(imageView);
        }
   }
}
```

And your application code looks like:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    public TableView<Apple> table;
    public TableColumn<Apple, String> nameColumn;
    public TableColumn<Apple, Image> imageColumn;

    Image downloadImage = new Image("download.jpg");
    Apple apple = new Apple("Bob",downloadImage);
    Apple apple2 = new Apple("John",downloadImage);
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        imageColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue().getImage()));

        imageColumn.setCellFactory(column -> new ImageCell());

        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getName()));
        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(apple2, apple));
    }
}
```

---

If you have a large number of distinct images in the table, which is probably unlikely, you should represent the path to the image in the model class instead:

```
public class Apple {

    private String name;
    private String imagePath;

    public Apple(String name, String imagePath) {
        this.name = name;
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImagePath() {
        return imagePath;
    }

    public void setImage(String imagePath) {
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }
}
```

Then your cell class needs to load the image:

```
public class ImageCell extends TableCell<Apple, String> {

    private static final IMAGE_SIZE = 20 ;
    private final ImageView imageView ;

    public TableCell() {
        imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setFitWidth(IMAGE_SIZE);
        imageView.setFitHeight(IMAGE_SIZE);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    }

   @Override
   protected void updateItem(String imagePath, boolean empty) {
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            imageView.setImage(new Image(imagePath));
            setGraphic(imageView);
        }
   }
}
```

and your application code has the obvious modifications:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    public TableView<Apple> table;
    public TableColumn<Apple, String> nameColumn;
    public TableColumn<Apple, String> imageColumn;

    Apple apple = new Apple("Bob", "download.jpg");
    Apple apple2 = new Apple("John", "download.jpg");
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        imageColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getImagePath()));

        imageColumn.setCellFactory(column -> new ImageCell());

        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getName()));
        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(apple2, apple));
    }
}
```