# JavaFX ClassCastException while trying to populate TableView with SQLite DB data

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, getter-setter, classcastexception

I have populated a TableView in a previous project but I have never done this with different datatypes. I am trying to populate 3 columns with data in my 'Concentrates' Table but I keep getting ClassCastException errors and my getters and setters do not appear to be working either.

I can System.print the values in the columns with the try while statement in My controller class but can't get them in my TableView.

I have looked around for a few hours and had a look at documentation. I believe that it is my 'ConcentrateVolume' column (mlRemaining variable) causing the issue as it's datatype is double but I am unsure of the correct syntax. I would have thought that the other 2 columns/variables would pull through as I have worked with those datatypes before and the code from a previous working project is more or less the same (not copy/pasted).

Any help is appreciated! I am using JDK 10.0.1 and SQLite Database.

Inventory.java

```
package PengVapour;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Inventory extends Application {
    public SimpleStringProperty brand = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty flavour = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleDoubleProperty mlRemaining = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

public String getBrand() {
    return brand.get();
}

public void setBrand(String brandStr) { brand.set(brandStr); }

public SimpleStringProperty brandProperty() {
    return brand;
}

public String getFlavour() {
    return flavour.get();
}

public void setFlavour(String flavourStr) {
    flavour.set(flavourStr);
}

public Double getMlRemaining() {
    return mlRemaining.get();
}

public void setMlRemaining(Double mlRemainingStr) { mlRemaining.set(mlRemainingStr); }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage inventoryStage) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../FXML/Inventory.fxml"));
        VBox root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("../CSS/PengVapour.css").toExternalForm());
        inventoryStage.setTitle("Peng Vapour - Inventory");
        inventoryStage.setScene(scene);
        inventoryStage.setResizable(false);
        inventoryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

InventoryController.java

```
package Controllers;

import PengVapour.Inventory;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class InventoryController implements Initializable {
    @FXML MenuItem fileExit;
    @FXML Button mainMenu;
    @FXML TableView table;
    @FXML TableColumn columnBrand;
    @FXML TableColumn columnFlavour;
    @FXML TableColumn columnMlRemaining;


private static Connection con;

private ObservableList<Inventory> invList;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    invList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    columnBrand.setCellFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Inventory, String>("brand")
    );

    columnFlavour.setCellFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Inventory, String>("flavour")
    );

    columnMlRemaining.setCellFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Inventory, Double>("ml")
    );

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\PengStation420\\IdeaProjects\\PengVapour\\PVIM.sqlite");

        ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT " +
                "Brand, Flavour, ConcentrateVolume " +
                "FROM Concentrates");
        while (rs.next()) {
            Inventory inv = new Inventory();
            inv.brand.set(rs.getString("Brand"));
            inv.flavour.set(rs.getString("Flavour"));
            inv.mlRemaining.set(rs.getDouble("ConcentrateVolume"));
            invList.add(inv);
        }
        table.setItems(invList);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InventoryController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

@FXML
public void menuBarFileExit(ActionEvent e) {
    System.exit(0);
}

@FXML
public void mainMenuButton(ActionEvent a) throws IOException {
    Node node = (Node) a.getSource();
    Stage stage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
    SceneController.changeScene(stage, "MainMenu.fxml", "Peng Vapour - Inventory Manager");
}
}
```

The error log I receive when I load the Inventory.fxml scene:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=58755:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1;C:\Users\PengStation420\IdeaProjects\PengVapour\out\production\PengVapour;C:\Users\PengStation420\Downloads\sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1\lib\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" PengVapour.MainMenu
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8865)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3876)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.controls@10.0.1/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn cannot be cast to javafx.controls@10.0.1/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn$CellDataFeatures
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.call(PropertyValueFactory.java:133)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.createCell(TableRowSkin.java:213)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.createCell(TableRowSkin.java:62)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.createCellAndCache(TableRowSkinBase.java:740)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.recreateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:734)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.<init>(TableRowSkinBase.java:158)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:213)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:897)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.access$000(Control.java:83)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9515)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.applyCss(Node.java:9602)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1715)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1692)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1801)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2638)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1245)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1211)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1218)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1218)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1218)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:590)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1773)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$2.preferredSize(Scene.java:394)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.preferredSize(SceneHelper.java:66)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$SceneModel.invalidated(Window.java:826)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setScene(Window.java:782)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.setScene(Stage.java:270)
    at Controllers.SceneController.changeScene(SceneController.java:15)
    at Controllers.MainMenuController.viewInventoryButton(MainMenuController.java:54)
    ... 58 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You are setting `PropertyValueFactory`s as the `cellFactory` of the `TableColumn`s. `PropertyValueFactory` is used as the `cellValueFactory`.

Comment: Thank you It has populated my 1st 2 columns now but my 3rd column's property (ml) is now being flagged as unreadable due to the provided classtype. Am I able to parse this so it can be passed to it's column in the table?

Comment: @James_D I realised that and I have made an edit with my changes. SimpleStringProperty changed to SimpleDoubleProperty in Inventory.java and removed String.valueOf() from InventoryController.java.

I'm now getting:

    WARNING: Can not retrieve property 'ml' in PropertyValueFactory: javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory@119afbc9 with provided class type: class PengVapour.Inventory
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read from unreadable property ml

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971109/javafx-tableview-not-showing-data-in-all-columns and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035478/javafx-propertyvaluefactory-not-populating-tableview

Comment: Thank you @James_D for your help. Don't know how I missed that, put it down to staring at the same thing for a while.