# JavaFX (java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

This is the file that launches the FXML
In the TableController file where I have the setItems(oblist) this is the source of the error. Something in my code it says is pointing NULL. I am trying to plug the GUI with data from mySQL database but I am not able to get the GUI to launch. This is the link to the youtube video I have been following. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoiQVoNil9Q

```
package cheapflights.system.gui;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXDB extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GUIGUI.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 


        launch(args);
}

}
```

This is the Main Code / Controller

```
package cheapflights.system.gui;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.mysql.cj.conf.IntegerProperty;

import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class TableController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<ModelTable> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ModelTable,IntegerProperty> col_flightID;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ModelTable,StringProperty> col_departingCity;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ModelTable,StringProperty> col_arrivalCity;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ModelTable,StringProperty> col_departureTime;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ModelTable,StringProperty> col_arrivalTime;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ModelTable,StringProperty> col_flightDate;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ModelTable,IntegerProperty> col_Quantity;

    ObservableList<ModelTable> oblist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Connection myConn = null;
        Statement myStmt = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;
        try {
            myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo", "flightuser" , "flightuser");

            myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

            // 3. Execute SQL query
            myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from Flight");

            while (myRs.next()) {
                oblist.add(new ModelTable(myRs.getInt("flightID"), myRs.getString("departingCity"), 
                        myRs.getString("arrivalCity"), myRs.getString("departureTime"), myRs.getString("arrivalTime"), myRs.getString("flightDate"), myRs.getInt("Quantity") ));
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Logger.getLogger(TableController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }




        col_flightID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("flightID"));
        col_departingCity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("departingCity"));
        col_arrivalCity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("arrivalCity"));
        col_departureTime.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("departureTime"));
        col_arrivalTime.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("arrivalTime"));
        col_flightDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("flightDate"));
        col_Quantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Quantity"));

    table.setItems(oblist);
    }

}
```

This is the ModelTable

```
package cheapflights.system.gui;

public class ModelTable {

    private int flightID;
    private String departingCity;
    private String arrivalCity;
    private String departureTime;
    private String arrivalTime;
    private String flightDate;
    private int Quantity;



    public ModelTable(int flightID, String departingCity, String arrivalCity,String departureTime, String arrivalTime, String flightDate, int Quantity) {
        this.flightID = flightID;
        this.departingCity = departingCity;
        this.arrivalCity= arrivalCity;
        this.departureTime = departureTime;
        this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
        this.flightDate = flightDate;
        this.Quantity = Quantity;
    }

    public int getFlight() {
        return flightID;
    }

    public void setFlight(int flightID) {
        this.flightID = flightID;
    }

    public String getarrivalTime() {
        return arrivalTime;
    }

    public void setarrivalTime(String arrivalTime) {
        this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    }

    public String getdepartureTime() {
        return departureTime;
    }

    public void setdepatureTime(String departureTime) {
        this.departureTime = departureTime;
    }

    public String getdepartingCity() {
        return departingCity;
    }

    public void setdepartingCity(String departingCity) {
        this.departingCity = departingCity;
    }

    public String getarrivalCity() {
        return arrivalCity;
    }
    public void setarrivalCity(String arrivalCity) {
        this.arrivalCity = arrivalCity;
    }

    public String getflightDate() {
        return flightDate;
    }
    public void setflightDate(String flightDate) {
        this.flightDate = flightDate;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return Quantity;
    }

    public void setquntity(int Quantity) {
        this.Quantity = Quantity;
    }


}
```

This is the FXML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller = "cheapflights.system.gui.TableController">
   <children>
      <TableView layoutX="-222.0" layoutY="-32.0" prefHeight="410.0" prefWidth="562.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="col_flightID" prefWidth="71.0" text="flightID" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="col_departingCity" prefWidth="71.0" text="departingCity" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="col_arrivalCity" prefWidth="89.0" text="arrivalCity" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="col_departureTime" prefWidth="75.0" text="departureTime" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="col_arrivalTime" prefWidth="95.0" text="arrivalTime" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="col_flightDate" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="flightDate" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="col_Quantity" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="73.0" text="Quantity" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This is the Run Time Error

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/dvd86/git/cis3270-project/TermProject/bin/cheapflights/system/gui/GUIGUI.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at cheapflights.system.gui.JavaFXDB.start(JavaFXDB.java:14)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cheapflights.system.gui.TableController.initialize(TableController.java:87)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application cheapflights.system.gui.JavaFXDB
```

This is the specific error that is shown in the Runtime Error

```
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at cheapflights.system.gui.TableController.initialize(TableController.java:87)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
        ... 17 more
    Exception running application cheapflights.system.gui.JavaFXDB
```

Comment: You didn't add a `fx:id` attribute to the `<TableView>` element. BTW: If you specify `AnchorPane.leftAnchor` and `AnchorPane.topAnchor` for the child of a `AnchorPane`, specifying `layoutX` and `layoutY` is pointless, since the layout algorithm of the pane determines those values.

Comment: @fabian hey thanks alot, that has gotten rid of the error now my GUI opens. New problem is now only the "Quantity" is being filled with data. The other fields are being left blank. Any idea why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035478/javafx-propertyvaluefactory-not-populating-tableview